Displaying new messages in messaging app built with TALL stack
I've built a messaging component for my web app and need it to scroll to the bottom of the chat automatically when loaded and when new messages are sent. I'm able to get it to scroll to the second to last message sent but no further. Any help getting this figured out would be much appreciated.
Here is the code I'm currently using:

<div class="w-3/4 border text-2xl border-gray-600 rounded-md mx-auto flex flex-col my-12"> 
    @if($activeConversation)
        <div class="bg-gray-800 text-4xl py-4 px-4 border-b border-gray-700 rounded-t-md">{{ $activeConversation->users()->where('user_id', '!=', auth()->user()->id)->value('name') }}</div>
            <div class="h-5/6 overflow-y-scroll" id="messageSection">
                <div class="h-full w-full py-4 mx-auto space-y-4 px-4 relative">
                    @foreach($activeConversation->messages()->get() as $message)
                        @if($message->sender_id === auth()->user()->id)
                            <x-message-sent :message="$message"/>
                        @else
                            <x-message-received :message="$message"/>                
                        @endif
                    @endforeach

                    <span id="snap"></span>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="w-full h-1/6 mt-4">

                <form wire:submit.throttle.100ms="send" class="flex h-full w-full space-x-4 px-4 py-4 border-t border-gray-700 bg-gray-800 rounded-md">
                    <textarea type="text" class="bg-gray-900 border border-gray-700 rounded-md w-full py-2 px-4 text-2xl mx-2 resize-none" rows="4" wire:model="message"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" id="sendMessage" class="bg-gray-700 border border-gray-600 rounded-md text-4xl h-min my-auto py-2 px-4 mx-2">Send</button>
                </form>
                @error('message')<div class="text-rose-500">{{$message}}</div>@enderror

            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
    </div>
    
    @script
    <script>

        messageSection = document.getElementById('messageSection');
        messageSection.scrollTop = messageSection.scrollHeight;

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
        {
            scrollChatToBottom();
        })

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#sendMessage').click(() =>
            {   
                scrollChatToBottom();
            });

            const channel = window.Echo.channel('conversation');

            channel.listen('NewMessage', (e) => 
            {
                scrollChatToBottom();
            })
        })

        function scrollChatToBottom() 
        {
            $('#messageSection').scrollTop($('#messageSection')[0].scrollHeight);
        }
    </script>
    @endscript

I've tried relocating the scroll function throughout the code and it doesn't seem to make a difference. I also wrote in the span element to try and have the page scroll to that but couldn't get it working either.

Maybe try using setTimeout() to delay the scroll slightly?
